# Form field values set with PDFBOX not visible in Adobe Reader

Tags: java, pdfbox, adobe-reader

I am having an issue with trying to set some from fields using Apache PDFBOX(1.8.5). I have a few different Static PDFs that I am using for testing. Using the following code, I can set the values of form fields, and save the resulting PDF. I can then open this PDF in Adobe Reader and see the results:

```
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
pdfTemplate.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
List fields = acroForm.getFields();     
Iterator fieldsIter = fields.iterator();        
while( fieldsIter.hasNext())
{
    PDField field = (PDField)fieldsIter.next();         
    if(field instanceof PDTextbox){
        ((PDTextbox)field).setValue("STATIC PDFBOX EDIT");
    }
}
```

And then I eventually save the form. For Static PDFs of:

- PDF Version: 1.6 (Acrobat 7.x)
- PDF Version: 1.7 (Acrobat 8.x)

This works just fine. I can open the Documents in Adobe Reader XI and see the correct values in the form.

For Static PDFs of:

- PDF Version: 1.7 Adobe Extension Level 3(Acrobat 9.x)
- PDF Version: 1.7 Adobe Extension Level 8(Acrobat X)
- PDF Version: 1.7 Adobe Extension Level 11(Acrobat XI)

This appears to not be working. When I open the resulting forms in Adobe Reader XI, the fields do not appear to be populated. But If I open the PDF in my Firefox or Chrome browser's PDF viewer, the fields show as populated there.

How can I set these fields so the values will appear when viewed in Adobe Reader XI?

EDIT: Sample PDFs can be found here: https://github.com/bamundson/PDFExample

Comment: Based on my experience with iText, I can think of two reasons: (1) a different setting of the NeedAppearances value; (2) wrong DA entries in the fields. What happens if you fill out the forms with iText?

Comment: Please supply the sample PDFs for analysis.

Comment: I have added a link in the original post to some sample PDFs I am using, versions 9, X, and XI. Writing new field values to these PDFs works fine with the latest version of iText

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The major difference between your PDFs is the form technology used:

- `Test_9.pdf` uses good ol'fashioned **AcroForm** forms;
- `Test_10.pdf` and `Test_10.pdf` on the other hand use a hybrid form with both an **AcroForm** representation and a **XFA** (Adobe XML Forms Architecture) representation.

XFA-aware PDF viewers (i.e. foremost Adobe Reader and Adobe Acrobat) use the **XFA** information from the file while XFA-unaware viewers (i.e. most others) use the **AcroForm** information.

PDFBox is mostly XFA-unaware. This means especially that the `PDField` objects returned by `PDAcroForm.getFields()` only represent the **AcroForm** information. Thus, your `((PDTextbox)field).setValue("STATIC PDFBOX EDIT")` calls only influence the **AcroForm** representation of the form.

This explains your observation

> When I open the resulting forms in Adobe Reader XI, the fields do not appear to be populated. But If I open the PDF in my Firefox or Chrome browser's PDF viewer, the fields show as populated there.

(As far as I know Firefox and Chrome integrated PDF viewers are XFA-unaware.)

So,

> How can I set these fields so the values will appear when viewed in Adobe Reader XI?

There essentially are two ways:

1. Remove the **XFA** entry from the **AcroForm** dictionary:

   ```
   acroForm.setXFA(null);
   ```

   If there is no **XFA**, Adobe Reader will use the **AcroForm** form information, too.
2. Edit both the **AcroForm** and the **XFA** information. You can retrieve the XFA information using

   ```
   PDXFAResource xr = acroForm.getXFA();
   ```

   and extract the underlying XML using

   ```
   xr.getDocument()
   ```

   Then you can edit the XML, put the resulting XML into a stream which you can wrap in a `PDXFAResource` which you then can set using `AcroForm.setXFA(...)`.

While option 1 certainly is much easier to implement, it only works for hybrid documents. If you also will have to edit pure XFA forms, you'll need to implement option 2.

> Writing new field values to these PDFs works fine with the latest version of iText

iText has a certain degree of explicit support for XFA forms.

Comment: I seriously wish I could give this +1000. Thank you for putting together such a helpful answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set NeedAppearances flag to true for acrofields.
Try following code snippet. It will display values in fields properly.

```
COSDictionary acroFormDict = new COSDictionary(); 
acroFormDict.setBoolean(COSName.getPDFName("NeedAppearances"), true);
acroFormDict.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Fields"), new COSArray());

// add a new AcroForm and add that to the document
PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(document, acroFormDict);
```

Comment: *It will display values in fields properly.* - No. That helps in some pure AcroForm situations but not in the case at hand.